# Is this the right way of using pd.get_dummies?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I have a dataframe that has both categorical and numerical variables. In my regression model, I would like to use both my categorical and numerical data.

```
df_w_dummies = pd.get_dummies(df, columns =['Publisher','Platform','Genre','Publisher_Country','Publisher_Continent'],
                            drop_first = True)
features_dummies = df_w_dummies.loc[:, df_w_dummies.columns != 'NA_Sales']
target_dummies = df_w_dummies.loc[:,'NA_Sales'].dropna()
```

I am also trying to avoid multicollinearity by adding the 'drop_first' keyword as True.

Any advice/input would be appreciated!

This is not very pretty... but here is an example of what some of the data would look like.

```
Name    Platform    Publisher   Chartz_Score    User_Score  Critic_Score    Global_Sales    NA_Sales    EU_Sales    JP_Sales    Other_Sales Year_of_Release Genre   Year    Total_Tweets    Publisher_Country   Publisher_Continent Publisher_Lat   Publisher_Long
Super Mario Bros.   Nintendo    Nintendo EAD    NaN 10.0    NaN 60.312336   89.184016   16.740672   53.505894   0.77    1985-10-18  Platform    1985.0  NaN MX  North America   14.88102    -92.27582
Wii Sports Resort   Nintendo    Nintendo EAD    8.8 8.0 8.8 49.311030   47.873538   51.344296   25.849397   3.02    2009-07-26  Sports  2009.0  296.0   GB  Europe  14.88102    -92.27582
```

Comment: show us sample data of df. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks good except when you .dropna()in target variable it may/may not be the same size with features variables.  So if you want do drop NaN values in the data, you should do it at the beginning.

```
df = df.dropna(subset=['NA_Sales'])
```